# Segmentation Fault using MEX-C function in MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I'm running a problem while creating a MEX-C function in MATLAB.

Here the thing, I want to return some data generated by my computational routine and put it in plhs[0].

I think I have a misunderstanding using C pointers and MEX files since I'm not really a C guy ...

Here's my code :

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    uint8_t *output_buffer;
    mwSize *size;
    size = (mwSize *) mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, size[0], mxUINT8_CLASS, mxREAL);
    output_buffer = (uint8_t *) mxGetData(plhs[0]);
    output_buffer = genData();
}
```

Basically my function genData() is generating some data and returns it.

I'd like to get the result as an output such that while typing :

`a = genData()` a would contain the plhs[0] content but that is not working.

I've tried using a `mxSetData(plhs[0], output_buffer)` . It works but crashes then when doing something else ...

I think the answer should be quite evident but I'm not really an expert in C.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What data does `genData()` produce? How does it return it? Please provide a [mre] so we can help you properly.

Comment: `mxGetPr(prhs[0])` is wrong if your MEX-file is called without input arguments. This can crash MATLAB hard. You need to always make sure `prhs[0]` exists before accessing it. Something like this: `if (nrhs<1) mexErrMsgTxt("Need at least one input argument!");` -- You are then casting the data pointer to `mwSize`, but you don't check what input type this is. Usually MATLAB arrays are of type `double`, but do check the type always!

Comment: So the ```getData()``` function is reading a shared memory and returns a pointer to it. The thing is that I do not need a right hand side argument since I'm always using the same key for the shm. Moreover the code I put in my post only returns zeros but MATLAB doesn't crash. But if I'm using ```mxSetData(plhs[0], output_buffer)```, I can get a result but I suspect a problem of freeing memory which causes MATLAB to crash.

Comment: Edit : I do need the phrs too, sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot attach native C/C++ memory to an mxArray via the mxSetData (and friends) API functions. That will screw up the MATLAB Memory Manager and will eventually lead to a crash.  You must either alter the genData function to use MATLAB API functions for the the memory allocation (mxMalloc, mxCalloc, etc.) in which case you could then use mxSetData, or you will need to copy the data from the genData returned pointer into the mxArray.
Also, your method of getting the size variable is not robust.  If the type of integer stored in prhs[0] does not match mwSize then you will either get a wrong answer or crash. So instead of this

```
mwSize *size;
size = (mwSize *) mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, size[0], mxUINT8_CLASS, mxREAL);
```

you should do something like this

```
mwSize size;
size = mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, size, mxUINT8_CLASS, mxREAL);
```

Finally, you should put in some checks up front to make sure there is a prhs[0] being passed in, that it is numeric, and that it is not empty and not complex, etc.
As an aside, the following line dos *not* attach a pointer to the mxArray:

```
output_buffer = genData();
```

It simply overwrites the value in the output_buffer variable ... nothing else.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I managed to solve the issue adding a ``mxMalloc`` and filling it with the data of my buffer and then using ``mxSetData``. So indeed, the crash came from the memory allocation ...

Comment: Doing that will create a memory leak unless you do this first:

mxFree(mxGetData(plhs[0]));

But rather than FREEing the data pointer and then doing an mxSetData with a different memory block, you could have just used the pointer returned from mxGetData(plhs[0]) directly and copy into that.